# ExecutorService shutdown in finalize()

Tags: java, executorservice, shutdown, finalize

I've got a class which manages a cache of objects.
The cache is cleaned once an hour via `ScheduledExecutorService`.
Is it ok to shutdown the `ExecutorService` via the class `finalize()` method?

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdownNow();
}
```

I'm currently running on Java 6.

Comment: Note that `finalize` is deprecated in Java 9. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) for an explanation of the shortcomings of using that method.

Comment: There is no guarantee it will be invoked.

Comment: I would probably implement AutoCloseable and provide an awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit) and shutdownNow() there.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm on Java 6!

Comment: @Andrew When the container, which may be EJB for example (and the JVM) shuts down, why shouldn't it be invoked?

Comment: Don't use finalize.  Finalize is not the Java equivalent of C's destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "call-this-last" method in Java.
The `finalize` method is actually a "eat-memory-and-maybe-don't-even-call-me" method in Java.

The ExecutorService has `shutdown` and a `shutdownNow`.
Use these,
but not in a `finalize` method.

Call `shutdown` when your app knows that it "wants to stop soonish".
Call `shutdownNow` when your app knows that it "wants to stop asap, but maybe not immediately`.

There is no way to instruct the `ExecutorService` to "stop now, don't wait".

Here is a [Brief ExecutorService Tutorial on Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the WeakReference class and it's use as a finalizer.

It is still dependent on the GC's reachability calculations which means it might not be called immediately, but it gets rid of the chance of zombie objects and a few other problems that plague the finalize pattern.